# ghostscript option to print duplexs

Tags: ghostscript

I have Xerox 7556 printer attached to windows server.

I am trying to use ghostscript commandline to print a pdf to that printer.

I can have it print fine but I want to force it to print duplex regardless of the printer settings.

I have tried `C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.55.0\bin\gswin32c.exe -dDuplex` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.55.0\bin\gswin32c.exe -dDuplex=true`.

Both just print simplex.

Google has not turned up the documentation for this command.

[EDIT] Add exact sample:`"C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.55.0\bin\gswin32c.exe" -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 -dDuplex -sOutputFile="%printer%\\theprnserv\Office Xerox WorkCenter 7556" "Desktop\SomeDocument.pdf"` and we got "Invalid PageMediaType" error message printed rather than the document.

Comment: That's not a programming question and as such off-topic here. Consider e.g. superuser.com.

Comment: The mswinpr2 device does not alter the Windows printer settings. It either launches a dialog so you can do so, or uses the **default** printer settings. -dDuplex does nothing at all with that device. According to the documentation if you set Duplex in the page device properties (using PostScript) then it will set it if the Windows printer driver supports it.

Comment: @KenS can you elaborate on the "set Duplex in the page device properties" statement?  We are generating these pdfs so we have flexibility on the creation of the .pdf.

Comment: It's nothing to do with the PDF, it is mentioned in the Ghostscript documentation for the mswinpr2 device.